# modify a regex to select all characters only if it doesn't contain a string

Tags: regex

Original regex:

```
<div class="msgln"(.*?)</div>
```

I'm trying to edit this regex so that it only selects the 'lines' that match this pattern:

`(begining literal string)` followed by `(any number of characters if they don't contain a specific string)` followed by the `(ending literal string)`

the common one I've found is `^((?!(cat|dog)).)*$` but it doesn't seem to work unless I'm not using it right.

Example:

```
<?php
$phpString = '<div class="msgln" a="dog" b="cat">stuff here</div>
<div>just another line</div>
<div class="msgln" a="another" b="one">stuff here</div>';

$phpString = preg_replace('~<div class="msgln"(.*?)</div>~i', "", $phpString);
?>
```

in the example what I'm trying to do is select only the first "line" in the string with `cat|dog` but not the third one with `another|one`. The original regex above selects both div lines with the `class="msgln"` as expected (ignoring the midle div line) so I'm trying to change the `(.*?)` part to select only the line with cat or dog in it.

I've looked but can't find a solution that works. Previous searches have a few common suggestions like the one above but none of them work.

I did find this

```
(.*)(?=(dog|cat))(.*)
```

which selects the line but trying the negative to select all the others

```
(.*)(?!=(dog|cat))(.*)
```

doesn't seem to work (with and without the =), it has the same effect as the original

```
(.*?)
```

Some info:

- Working with PHP
- No database, have to work from flat files
- Have to do several other things to the string which has the potential to get fairly large. Regex is inherently faster based on test data

Comment: Before you get *Zalgo'd*, use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: These are the cases where you should refrain from using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the pattern `^((?!(cat|dog)).)*$` does is position the beginning of the string `^` and check if the string does not contain cat or dog. (`(?!foo)` is a negative lookahead). If this is the case it will start matching actual characters `(.)*` from the beginning of the string until the end `$`.

In your scenario, if you want to match a string that does not(!) contain the words "another" or "one", simply change the words: `^((?!(another|one)).)+$`. Note I changed the `*` (zero or more) at the end to `+` (one or more), because with the former it is possible that the pattern matches empty strings of length zero which can cause problems :).

Comment: The string in question in within another so a slight mod to ((?!(another|one)).)+ seems to work in testers like https://regex101.com, but when i put it in my PHP file it doesn't seem to work. The PHP line i'm using is preg_replace('~<div class="msgln"((?!(dog|cat)).)+</div>~i', "", $chat)...i've tried gi and i flags and neither work :(

Comment: You might have to add the multiline flag 'm' and also add the ^ and $ to the regex again. This way the regex will treat newlines as 'start/end' of the string characters as well. Right now if you're text is treated as a single string the regex would not match indeed. 'g' flag should not matter, it only sets your regex to keep matching after the first find. 'i' flag would matter if your actual text has uppercase letters while the pattern has lowercase only.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on gjzwiers suggestion here is the the final regex that seems to be working (PHP preg_replace)

```
$data = preg_replace('~<div class="msgln"((?!(dog|cat)).)+</div>~im', "", $data);
```

I forgot about the 'm' flag.